# Limit Number records when Grouped

Tags: mysql

I want to get top ten products which are sold most in a particular month of the particular year. I did the following:

```
SELECT Year(date1), Month(date1), `ProductID`, sum(`Price`*`Quantity`)"Sales" 
FROM `products`
Group By Year(date1), Month(date1), ProductId
order by Year(date1), Month(date1), Sales Desc;
```

But, It gives me all the products, I want only top 10 products.
 can't understand to where apply Limit of 10 records,

Comment: I think that you're going to have an issue with this, since you are listing by year/month/productId.  A straight "limit" will give you the top 10 year/month/productID combinations, not just the top 10 products

Answer (score 1):

If you're sort is setup as you wanted, just add

```
LIMIT 0,10
```

to your query

Answer (score 0):

Use the mysql inbuilt function Limit at the end of your select query

```
LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}
            ^                    ^
        Starting tuple     Number of tuples
```

For more reading [Go Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider restructuring the group by clause, order by, where clause and usage of date_format

```
SELECT date_format(date1) as month, `ProductID`, sum(`Price`*`Quantity`)"Sales" 
FROM `products`
WHERE date1 > '2013-01-01' and date1 < '2013-02-01'
Group By ProductId
order by Sales Desc
Limit 0,10
;
```